# How to create a perspective without showing it

Tags: rcp, e4

Is there any way to initialize a perspective without actually opening/showing it?

I would like to fill a part within that perspective with data. The following only works, if the part lies within an already open perspective.

```
partService.showPart("org.test.mypart", PartState.CREATE)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't think the UI code of the part will be initilized until you actually show the part so it doesn't seem to achieve anything.

Comment: @greg-449: The information which I am sending to the part is only temporarily available. As a workaround, I save the data and request it during part creation. But I would like to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
partService.createPart("org.test.mypart");
```

which 'creates a new part of the given id.'